# How to get JIRA issues assigned to the current user using the JIRA REST API?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to get a list of issues assigned to the current logged in user using the JIRA REST API, but I can't find any documentation on how to do that.

What do I need to do in order to get the issues assigned to the current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the issues you want to receive by using jql. 
In your case `rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=currentuser()` should do the trick.

[Here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e379) is the relevant part of the documentation of the REST api and [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching+Functions#AdvancedSearchingFunctions-currentUser()) is the description of the used jql-function.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `currentuser()`, and it's not mentioned in the docs you linked to. I have a follow up question if you know the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210004/how-to-get-jira-agile-issues-assigned-to-the-current-sprint-for-the-current-user

Comment: I added the link to the jql-functions to my answer.

Comment: when I use ```rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=currentuser()```, I am getting the following error:
```bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('```

But when I use ```rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=currentuser```, I get following error:
```{"startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":0,"issues":[],"warningMessages":["The value 'currentuser' does not exist for the field 'assignee'."]}```