# How to get JIRA Agile issues assigned to the current sprint for the current user using the JIRA REST API?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, jira-agile, greenhopper

I'm getting started working with the JIRA REST API. I've learned how to get all the issues assigned to the current user:

```
rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=currentuser()
```

...now I am trying to filter those by the current sprint. I think this functionality is provided by the JIRA Agile (Greenhopper) plugin, but I can't find any documentation for it. I came across some interesting data which appears to be the identifier for the sprint that the issue is assigned to:

```
customfield_10005: [
  "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@3094f872[rapidViewId=30,state=CLOSED,name=Sprint 2014-06-02,startDate=2014-06-02T00:00:37.672-07:00,endDate=2014-06-08T11:59:00.000-07:00,completeDate=2014-06-09T10:23:13.983-07:00,id=45]"
]
```

...but it just looks like a serialized mess. How can I query for the issues assigned to the current sprint?

Comment: I have never worked with jira agile, but maybe you could use this as a starting point? https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching+Functions#AdvancedSearchingFunctions-openSprints()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method you are looking for is

`openSprints()`

Its only working with JIRA Agile Version 6.5 or higher.

//* EDIT: Greenhopper got renamed to JIRA Agile *//

The method definition is:

> Search for issues that are assigned to a Sprint which has not yet been
>   completed. (Note that it is possible for an issue to belong to both a
>   completed Sprint(s) and an incomplete Sprint(s).)

So this should work for you then

```
assignee in (currentUser()) AND sprint in openSprints()
```

Regards

Comment: So use the REST API resource that lets you run a search and use the openSprints() as part of the JQL passed to the search

Comment: so adjust your answer like "This is a two way process: first, define a filter ... then second make a rest call that uses that filter ... " or "Use the rest API call [search](https://bunjil.jira-dev.com/plugins/servlet/restbrowser#/resource/api-2-search) and inside the parameter jql, use ..."

Comment: @mliebelt "Use the rest API call search and inside the parameter jql, use ..." the OP already has that part in his Question, or am I totally fuzzy right now?

Comment: The devil is  in the details. We have made some experiences with the JIRA REST API the past 6 months, and sometimes, there are some subtleties that have to be made explicit. So what is the syntax to use your query "assignee in ..." inside the REST API call?

Comment: [Check out this answer to get the active sprint for a specific project key](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27725082/1975259)

Comment: @mliebelt as in my Answer jql=assignee%20in(currentUser())AND%20sprint%20in%20openSprints()